# Plesk 12 - Access domain/webspace before DNS point to server

Tags: dns, plesk

I'm using Plesk 12 to manage my domains and websites. At the moment I need to move a website from another provider to me.

Before I change the DNS entries to point to my server. I'd like to check if everything is working correct. So is there a way to access a webspace with a domain set up, that is actually not pointing to my server?

Answer (score 1):

If you have Linux on your local computer, you can edit the hosts file and add the domain and IP address of the new server.

Remember to add your domain to new plesk.

Your web browser will direct you to your client website with the new provider.

Comment: hi, that's also possible with windows. but is there no other way? for example using the serverip/new-domain.tld or something like that?

Comment: @invictus U can create folder domain.com for example in root where Your new provider is. After that access to site by serverip/domain.com is posible.

Remember that sometimes configuration of Your website/cms or other can require main url change in configuration file.

Here is simple example:

i created folder in root of my www folder called growthaces.com
http://185.5.99.3/growthaces.com/
orginal site
http://growthaces.com/

Comment: But plesk automatically places all sites in var/www/vhosts